# Variable does not contain carriage return when created in SSIS script component

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have created a c# variable inside the script component in SSIS. My plan is to concatenate the previous variable value with that of the data from each row passing through the data flow plus a new line. I will then assign the value of that variable to an SSIS variable to use inside the Send Mail Task.

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    string myString;

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        this.Variables.emailContent = myString;
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        myString = myString + Row.column1 + ", " + Row.column2 + Environment.NewLine;
    }

}
```

My problem is that when the email is sent `Environment.NewLine` doesn't appear to doing anything, the SSIS variable `emailContent` is sent in the email on one line.

I have also tried using `\n` but have not had any luck.

What is interesting is that when I write the variable directly to a text file, the new line appears as expected.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with how the data is stored in the variable and not how the e-mail message is interpreted/displayed? (i.e. if e-mail is *somewhere* interpreted as HTML then all newlines are treated as spaces.)

Comment: Good call. Turns out Outlook, when receiving the email, was having none of it plain text. Odd that it worked if I added Environment.NewLine twice, although a horrible solution. What I have done instead is remove the Send Email Task and perform the whole operation in C# and format the message as HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\r\n`

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        myString = myString + Row.column1 + ", " + Row.column2 + "\r\n";
    }
```

Note that these symbols are equivalent to:

```
\r : CR
\n : LF
```

Also try duplicating backslashes *(because you are working with SSIS variables)*

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        myString = myString + Row.column1 + ", " + Row.column2 + "\\r\\n";
    }
```